# mytrack.duration retorna NaN

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

Esta retornando NaN, alguém tem uma solução?
Segue o código:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="mytrack" controls>
        <source src="Jinxed.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(mytrack.duration);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente adicionar o evento `loadeddata`, exemplo:

```
mytrack.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
    alert(this.duration);
});
```

Da forma que você está tentando fazer, o script executa antes do áudio ter carregado, por isso retorna `NaN`. Com o evento `loadeddata` ele executa quando os dados estiverem disponíveis.

**[HTML Audio/Video DOM loadeddata Event](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadeddata.asp)**

**[Exemplo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhgfymzt/2/)**

Comment: Retornou NaN tanto aqui no meu código, quanto no seu no JSFiddle? Será que é o navegador?

Comment: @AsuraKhan testei novamente e esta retornando `NaN`, mais é porque por algum motivo o arquivo mp3 que coloquei como exemplo no fiddle não esta sendo localizado. :/

Comment: no meu caso ele localiza o audio, mas não funciona e os códigos estão idênticos. São 2 linhas afinal.

Comment: @AsuraKhan veja a edição, se dessa forma funciona para seu caso.

Comment: Agora funcionou, mas eu não entendi nada. Conheço o eventlistener e seu uso com callback, mas esse this aí..eu sou meio burro com "this" . Ficarei agradecido se me explicar. Inclusive do porquê não funcionar do outro método.

Comment: @AsuraKhan veja a edição com a explicação.

Comment: Valeu muito obrigado.